dry writing phrase origin, original texts
Is there any origin for the phrase "dry writing" that supposes it was writing created without the influence of alcohol? I only see the idea dry as in barren https://www.etymonline.com/word/dry, as in not interesting or not flamboyant. As another idea, could the origin be from not lubricated, meaning it is hard to pass from one idea to the next? Does anyone have a good origin story or source? In what texts did this phrase first appear?

This use of "dry" is relatively recent. The OED has this entry for "dry" first recorded in 1941 -- Additional sense Also by extension, abstaining from alcoholic drink, esp. after becoming addicted; having stopped taking an addictive drug. -1941 Dry, sober. J. Smiley, Hash House Lingo 23 [NB "hash house" = cheap restarant]

In the context of soldering electrical connections, a dry joint has nothing to do with the absence of alcohol or water.

The Online Etymological Dictionary [below; adjusted] claims that the 'vanilla', 'humdrum' sense predates the 'abstinence' sense:

dry

Sense of "uninteresting, tedious" is from 1620s.
Sense of "not involving alcoholic drink" (dry feast, one at which no liquor is served, is from late 15c.
Sense of "[of places] prohibiting alcoholic drink" is from 1870


This refutes your first suggestion.
Obviously, there is a conceptual metaphor involved in various senses, with
                   'dry' ∼ 'dusty' ... or 'barren' ∼ 'unoiled' ∼ 'stale, uninspiring' ... or 'unfruitful'.
(metaphorical association shown by the symbol  ∼ meaning 'represented in another domain by')
The exact etymology concerning which sense developed from which other will probably never be confirmed.

Dry prose shows up more often than dry writing, in Google Ngram in the early 19th century. For example, the following is a hilarious critique of bad poetry:
https://books.google.com/books?id=lGFpYzEJ4UEC&pg=PA377&dq=%22dry+prose%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSjqvmw6yGAxXyFTQIHXOiDM8Q6AF6BAgIEAM#v=onepage&q=%22dry%20prose%22&f=false
I see no indication that dry refers to an absence of alchoholic encouragement. The phrase “dry writing” is often followed by the word “paper,” thus a false positive.

Dry related to abstinence is late 19th century so it's later than dry prose.
